# javascript create array from for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a years range stored into two variables. I want to create an array of the years in the range.

something like:

```
var yearStart = 2000;
var yearEnd = 2040;

var arr = [];

for (var i = yearStart; i < yearEnd; i++) {

     var obj = {
        ... 
     };

      arr.push(obj);
}
```

What should I put inside the obj ?

The array I'd like to generate would be like:

```
arr = [2000, 2001, 2003, ... 2039, 2040]
```

Comment: I posted an answer which gives both highest number as well as all values if highest number is greater then your certain number

Answer (score 69, accepted):

even shorter if you can lose the yearStart value:

```
var yearStart = 2000;
var yearEnd = 2040;

var arr = [];

while(yearStart < yearEnd+1){
  arr.push(yearStart++);
}
```

UPDATE:
If you can use the ES6 syntax you can do it the way proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650961/functional-way-to-iterate-over-range-es6-7#30651275):

```
let yearStart = 2000;
let yearEnd = 2040;
let years = Array(yearEnd-yearStart+1)
    .fill()
    .map(() => yearStart++);
```

Answer (score 32):

You need to push `i`

```
var yearStart = 2000;
var yearEnd = 2040;

var arr = [];

for (var i = yearStart; i < yearEnd+1; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}
```

Then, your resulting array will be:

> `arr = [2000, 2001, 2003, ... 2039, 2040]`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 9):

```
var yearStart = 2000;
var yearEnd = 2040;

var arr = [];

for (var i = yearStart; i <= yearEnd; i++) {

     arr.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `obj` and just do this inside your for loop:

```
arr.push(i);
```

Also, the `i < yearEnd` condition will not include the final year, so change it to `i <= yearEnd`.