# functional way to iterate over range (ES6/7)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

What is the best way to do the below in more functional way (with ES6/ES7)

```
let cols = [];
for (let i =0; i <= 7; i++) {
   cols.push(i * i);
}
return cols;
```

I tried like,

```
return [ ...7 ].map(i => {
  return i * i;
});
```

but that translated to

```
[].concat(7).map(function (n) {
  return n * n;
});
```

which is not what I expected.

### EDIT:

@pavlo. Indeed, that was a mistake. I was using JSX, and for example, I want 7 divs, (untested)

```
let cols = [];
    for (let i =0; i <= 7; i++) {
       cols.push(<div id={i}> ...  </div>)
    }
    return cols;
```

so the idea was indeed to reduce the number of temp variables and procedural feel.

Comment: You want to square every number 1-7?

Comment: In the first example you probably mean `cols.push(i * i)` instead of `return i * i`.

Answer (score 311, accepted):

One can create an empty array, fill it (otherwise map will skip it) and then map indexes to values:

```
Array(8).fill(0).map((_, i) => i * i);
```

Comment: If don't need the result array from map, and you want to keep the 'for' word in there, you could use `Array(8).fill().forEach((_,i)=>console.log(i))` or `[...Array(8)].forEach((_,i)=>console.log(i))`

Comment: Note that this code will fail in Typescript, unless you add `undefined` as a first argument to `fill`. According to [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25392#issuecomment-804255033) Typescript maintainers seem to be against this specific use of the `Array.prototype.fill`.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. For practical purposes, I've updated the answer to use `.fill(0)`.

Comment: Or `Array.from({length: 8}, (_, i) => i * i)`.

Comment: Creating an array just to loop over certain number of times, peak JavaScript.

Comment: @EternalObserver the gain in readability and chain-ability is worth any perceived performance impact (which is most certainly negligible).

Answer (score 99):

### ES7 Proposal

**Warning:** Unfortunately I believe most popular platforms have dropped support for comprehensions. See below for the well-supported ES6 method

You can always use something like:

```
[for (i of Array(7).keys()) i*i];
```

Running this code on Firefox:

> [ 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36 ]

This works on Firefox (it was a proposed ES7 feature), but it has been dropped from the spec. IIRC, Babel 5 with "experimental" enabled supports this.

This is your best bet as array-comprehension are used for just this purpose. You can even write a range function to go along with this:

```
var range = (u, l = 0) => [ for( i of Array(u - l).keys() ) i + l ]
```

Then you can do:

```
[for (i of range(5)) i*i] // 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25
[for (i of range(5,3)) i*i] // 9, 16, 25
```

### ES6

A nice way to do this any of:

```
[...Array(7).keys()].map(i => i * i);
Array(7).fill().map((_,i) => i*i);
[...Array(7)].map((_,i) => i*i);
```

This will output:

> [ 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36 ]

Comment: @vihan1086: array comprehensions were proposed for ES many times, but didn't make it in the spec. `.map(i => i*i)` was deemed to be so much simpler :-)

Comment: This didn't work when I tried it: Array(7).keys().map(i => i * i);   The keys() returned an iterator. This works however: Array.from(Array(7).keys()).map(i => i * i)  notice the need to explicitly load the iterator into another array.

Comment: @arcseldon No it does not work. I'm not sure what I was thinking when I posted :p Will fix

Comment: @Bergi They missed the ES6 spec but they are in the ES7, if you use a transpiler such as babel or target Firefox, you usually can set an "experimental" option to enable time

Comment: `[...Array(7)]` works just fine without the `.keys()` part.

Comment: Array comprehension is not part of ES7. It's not even a proposal anymore as far as I can tell.

Comment: @FelixKling no but I think babel with experimental turned on supports it so I'll leave it.

Comment: At least don't claim they are in ES7. That will only confuse people. I don't think Babel supports them anymore: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/ .

Comment: @FelixKling iirc, they were proposed for ES7. I will update

Comment: Is there any way to get a sense of the space and time efficiency of this? Say, on the magnitude of `1e6`? Or do we just have to experiment?

Comment: @BaseZen can't say these would on the surface be efficient given that we would be constructing a non-holey array of a huge size with something like `1e6`. JS engine might do under the hood optimization but I don't have any specifics if that happens

Answer (score 39):

Here's an approach using generators:

```
function* square(n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) yield i*i;
}
```

Then you can write

```
console.log(...square(7));
```

Another idea is:

```
[...Array(5)].map((_, i) => i*i)
```

`Array(5)` creates an unfilled five-element array. That's how `Array` works when given a single argument. We use the spread operator to create an array with five undefined elements. That we can then map. See http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/07/sequences-using-javascript-array.html.

Alternatively, we could write

```
Array.from(Array(5)).map((_, i) => i*i)
```

or, we could take advantage of the second argument to `Array#from` to skip the `map` and write

```
Array.from(Array(5), (_, i) => i*i)
```

A horrible hack which I saw recently, which I do **not** recommend you use, is

```
[...1e4+''].map((_, i) => i*i)
```

Comment: `Array(...Array(5))` is better expressed as `[...Array(5)]`.

Comment: I am surprised `Array(5).map((_,i) => i+1)` doesn't work, does anyone know why?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen A year+ late, but `map` [skips empty slots in an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#description) "`callbackFn` is invoked only for array indexes which have assigned values. It is not invoked for empty slots in sparse arrays.", and `Array(5)` creates and array with 5 empty slots.

Comment: One could also do `Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => i*i)`.