# How to generate range of numbers from 0 to n in ES2015 only?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have always found the `range` function missing from JavaScript as it is available in python and others? Is there any concise way to generate range of numbers in ES2015 ?

EDIT: MY question is different from the mentioned duplicate as it is specific to ES2015 and not ECMASCRIPT-5. Also I need the range to be starting from 0 and not specific starting number (though it would be good if that is there)

Comment: The answer is the same for ES5 and ES6.

Comment: But you can always use some og the new concepts such as generators, new array methods etc. in ES2015. That gives you extra set of tools to achieve the task

Comment: I think @Delapouite has the perfect answer to this in [comments to an answer to the duplicated question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29559488/918910): `[...Array(n).keys()]`.

Comment: related: [Is there a mechanism to loop x times in ES6 without mutable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30452263/1048572) and [functional way to iterate over range in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30650961/1048572)

Comment: `[...Array(5)].map((_,i) => i+1)`

Answer (score 364, accepted):

You can use the spread operator on the keys of a freshly created array.

`[...Array(n).keys()]`

or

`Array.from(Array(n).keys())`

The `Array.from()` syntax is necessary if working with TypeScript

Comment: Sweet: `function range (start, end) { return [...Array(1+end-start).keys()].map(v => start+v) }`

Comment: This doesn't work in typescript because keys() returns an Array Iterator instead of an Array. Checkout aditya-singh's answer for a more universal approach.

Comment: …… or **`Array.from(Array(n).keys())`**.

Comment: @DavidGonzalezShannon Do you know why `[...Array(n).keys()]` doesn't work in Typescript? Is it an intentional deviation from other JS implementations?

Comment: Hey @StuCox I have no idea why but it transpiles it to `Array(5).keys().slice()` and slice is not a method of array iterator. Here's an example of it not working https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20range%20%3D%20%5B...Array(5).keys()%5D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(range)%3B

Comment: @DavidDomingo add the downlevelIteration flag or change your target to es6 or later.

Comment: Perf test here: https://jsbench.me/qvk74npuvm/1 
Dr Axel's thoughts on array perf here: https://2ality.com/2018/12/creating-arrays.html#tip%3A-array-performance-usually-doesn%E2%80%99t-matter-that-much :P

Answer (score 124):

I also found one more intuitive way using `Array.from`:

```
const range = n => Array.from({length: n}, (value, key) => key)
```

Now this `range` function will return all the numbers starting from 0 to n-1

A modified version of the range to support `start` and `end` is:

```
const range = (start, end) => Array.from({length: (end - start)}, (v, k) => k + start);
```

**EDIT**
As suggested by @marco6, you can put this as a static method if it suits your use case

```
Array.range = (start, end) => Array.from({length: (end - start)}, (v, k) => k + start);
```

and use it as

```
Array.range(3, 9)
```

Comment: Nice one! Why don't we extend Array static interface with it?
In typescript works great with:
`interface ArrayConstructor {  range(n: number): number[]; }`
`Array.range = n => Array.from({length: n}, (value, key) => key);`

And then everywhere `Array.range(x)...`

Comment: `[ts] Property 'range' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'`. thouths?

Comment: Overriding built-ins is considered bad practice in javascript now.

Comment: Stick to range as util function or define your own object (with a type if using TS) and call it ArrayV2 or something. Don't mess with built in prototypes, it can backfire horribly.

Answer (score 54):

### With Delta/Step

##### smallest and one-liner

```js
[...Array(N)].map((_, i) => from + i * step);
```

Examples and other alternatives

```js
[...Array(10)].map((_, i) => 4 + i * 2);
//=> [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]

Array.from(Array(10)).map((_, i) => 4 + i * 2);
//=> [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]

Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map(i => 4 + i * 2);
//=> [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]

[...Array(10).keys()].map(i => 4 + i * -2);
//=> [4, 2, 0, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10, -12, -14]

Array(10).fill(0).map((_, i) => 4 + i * 2);
//=> [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]

Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => 4 + i * -2);
//=> [4, 2, 0, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10, -12, -14]
```

##### Range Function

```js
const range = (from, to, step) =>
  [...Array(Math.floor((to - from) / step) + 1)].map((_, i) => from + i * step);

range(0, 9, 2);
//=> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

##### As Iterators

```js
class Range {
  constructor(total = 0, step = 1, from = 0) {
    this[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
      for (let i = 0; i < total; yield from + i++ * step) {}
    };
  }
}

[...new Range(5)]; // Five Elements
//=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[...new Range(5, 2)]; // Five Elements With Step 2
//=> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
[...new Range(5, -2, 10)]; // Five Elements With Step -2 From 10
//=>[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
[...new Range(5, -2, -10)]; // Five Elements With Step -2 From -10
//=> [-10, -12, -14, -16, -18]

// Also works with for..of loop
for (i of new Range(5, -2, 10)) console.log(i);
// 10 8 6 4 2
```

##### As Generators Only

```js
const Range = function* (total = 0, step = 1, from = 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < total; yield from + i++ * step) {}
};

Array.from(Range(5, -2, -10));
//=> [-10, -12, -14, -16, -18]

[...Range(5, -2, -10)]; // Five Elements With Step -2 From -10
//=> [-10, -12, -14, -16, -18]

// Also works with for..of loop
for (i of Range(5, -2, 10)) console.log(i);
// 10 8 6 4 2

// Lazy loaded way
const number0toInf = Range(Infinity);
number0toInf.next().value;
//=> 0
number0toInf.next().value;
//=> 1
// ...
```

#### From-To with steps/delta

##### using iterators

```js
class Range2 {
  constructor(to = 0, step = 1, from = 0) {
    this[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
      let i = 0,
        length = Math.floor((to - from) / step) + 1;
      while (i < length) yield from + i++ * step;
    };
  }
}
[...new Range2(5)]; // First 5 Whole Numbers
//=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

[...new Range2(5, 2)]; // From 0 to 5 with step 2
//=> [0, 2, 4]

[...new Range2(5, -2, 10)]; // From 10 to 5 with step -2
//=> [10, 8, 6]
```

##### using Generators

```js
const Range2 = function* (to = 0, step = 1, from = 0) {
  let i = 0,
    length = Math.floor((to - from) / step) + 1;
  while (i < length) yield from + i++ * step;
};

[...Range2(5, -2, 10)]; // From 10 to 5 with step -2
//=> [10, 8, 6]

let even4to10 = Range2(10, 2, 4);
even4to10.next().value;
//=> 4
even4to10.next().value;
//=> 6
even4to10.next().value;
//=> 8
even4to10.next().value;
//=> 10
even4to10.next().value;
//=> undefined
```

Comment: Your updated TypeScript version doesn't work. It creates an empty array with the indicated size. You need to use Array.from with Array.keys with TypeScript.
`Array.from(Array(~~((to - from) / step) + 1).keys())`

Answer (score 30):

**For numbers 0 to 5**

```
[...Array(5).keys()];
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 16):

A lot of these solutions build on instantiating real Array objects, which can get the job done for a lot of cases but can't support cases like `range(Infinity)`. You could use a simple generator to avoid these problems and support infinite sequences:

```
function* range( start, end, step = 1 ){
  if( end === undefined ) [end, start] = [start, 0];
  for( let n = start; n < end; n += step ) yield n;
}
```

Examples:

```
Array.from(range(10));     // [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
Array.from(range(10, 20)); // [ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ]

i = range(10, Infinity);
i.next(); // { value: 10, done: false }
i.next(); // { value: 11, done: false }
i.next(); // { value: 12, done: false }
i.next(); // { value: 13, done: false }
i.next(); // { value: 14, done: false }
```

Answer (score 14):

So, in this case, it would be nice if **Number** object would behave like an Array object with the spread operator.

For instance **Array** object used with the spread operator:

```
let foo = [0,1,2,3];
console.log(...foo) // returns 0 1 2 3
```

It works like this because Array object has a built-in iterator.
In our case, we need a **Number** object to have a similar functionality:

```
[...3] //should return [0,1,2,3]
```

To do that we can simply create Number iterator for that purpose.

```
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function *() {
   for(let i = 0; i <= this; i++)
       yield i;
}
```

Now it is possible to create ranges from 0 to N with the spread operator.

> [...N] // now returns 0 ... N array

http://jsfiddle.net/01e4xdv5/4/

Cheers.

Comment: Just because it is possible it doesn't mean you should. Messing with prototypes is bad practice, rather create a new proto if you have, not use built in protos for that.

Answer (score 8):

Range with step ES6, that works similar to python `list(range(start, stop[, step]))`:

```js
const range = (start, stop, step = 1) => {
  return [...Array(stop - start).keys()]
    .filter(i => !(i % Math.round(step)))
    .map(v => start + v)
}
```

Examples:

```
range(0, 8) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
range(4, 9) // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
range(4, 9, 2) // [4, 6, 8] 
range(4, 9, 3) // [4, 7]
```

Comment: Nice add to the question! This helped me out to get much cleaner code in my Angular 8 html *ngFor loop templates.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a generator function, which creates the range lazily only when needed:

```js
function* range(x, y) {
  while (true) {
    if (x <= y)
      yield x++;

    else
      return null;
  }
}

const infiniteRange = x =>
  range(x, Infinity);
  
console.log(
  Array.from(range(1, 10)) // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
);

console.log(
  infiniteRange(1000000).next()
);
```

You can use a higher order generator function to map over the `range` generator:

```js
function* range(x, y) {
  while (true) {
    if (x <= y)
      yield x++;

    else
      return null;
  }
}

const genMap = f => gx => function* (...args) {
  for (const x of gx(...args))
    yield f(x);
};

const dbl = n => n * 2;

console.log(
  Array.from(
    genMap(dbl) (range) (1, 10)) // [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
);
```

If you are fearless you can even generalize the generator approach to address a much wider range (pun intended):

```js
const rangeBy = (p, f) => function* rangeBy(x) {
  while (true) {
    if (p(x)) {
      yield x;
      x = f(x);
    }

    else
      return null;
  }
};

const lte = y => x => x <= y;

const inc = n => n + 1;

const dbl = n => n * 2;

console.log(
  Array.from(rangeBy(lte(10), inc) (1)) // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
);

console.log(
  Array.from(rangeBy(lte(256), dbl) (2)) // [2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256]
);
```

Keep in mind that generators/iterators are inherently stateful that is, there is an implicit state change with each invocation of `next`. State is a mixed blessing.

Answer (score 2):

To support delta

```
const range = (start, end, delta) => {
  return Array.from(
    {length: (end - start) / delta}, (v, k) => (k * delta) + start
  )
};
```

Answer (score 2):

### How about just mapping ....

Array(n).map((value, index) ....) is 80% of the way there. But for some odd reason it does not work. But there is a workaround.

```
Array(n).map((v,i) => i) // does not work
Array(n).fill().map((v,i) => i) // does dork
```

For a range

```
Array(end-start+1).fill().map((v,i) => i + start) // gives you a range
```

Odd, these two iterators return the same result: `Array(end-start+1).entries()` and `Array(end-start+1).fill().entries()`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with a one liner with step support like this one:

`((from, to, step) => ((add, arr, v) => add(arr, v, add))((arr, v, add) => v < to ? add(arr.concat([v]), v + step, add) : arr, [], from))(0, 10, 1)`

The result is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7 ,8 ,9]`.

Comment: Is this the Y-combinator?

Comment: It follows the idea of Y-combinator.

Answer (score 1):

This function will return an integer sequence.

```
const integerRange = (start, end, n = start, arr = []) =>
  (n === end) ? [...arr, n]
    : integerRange(start, end, start < end ? n + 1 : n - 1, [...arr, n]);

$> integerRange(1, 1)
<- Array [ 1 ]

$> integerRange(1, 3)
<- Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]

$> integerRange(3, -3)
<- Array(7) [ 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Few more ways to do

```js
// Using `repeat` and `map`
const gen = n => [...'.'.repeat(n)].map((_,i) => i);

console.log('gen ', gen(5));


// Using `repeat` and `split`
const gen2 = n => ' '.repeat(n).split('').map((_,i) => i);

console.log('gen2 ', gen2(5));

// Using `concat` with recursive approach
const gen3 = n => n ? gen3(n-1).concat(n-1) : [];

console.log('gen3 ', gen3(5));


const range = (start, end, step = 1) =>
  start > end ? [] : [start].concat(range(start + step, end, step));

console.log('range', range(2, 10,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const keys = Array(n).keys();
[...Array.from(keys)].forEach(callback);
```

in Typescript

Comment: There's no reason to use both `Array.from` and spread syntax. And then it's exactly the same as the existing answer.

Comment: Just wanna point out `[...Array(n).keys()]` does not work in Typescript.

Comment: Then use `Array.from(Array(n).keys())`. I'm pretty sure it should work though, what does the literal with spread syntax transpile to?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation that doesn't use `Array`.

```
let range = (n, l=[], delta=1) => {
  if (n < 0) { 
    return l 
  }
  else {
    l.unshift(n)
    return range(n - delta, l) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and concise use of iterators.

```js
const range = (i, n) => ({
    [Symbol.iterator]: () => ({ 
        next: () => ({ done: i > n, value: i++  }) 
    })
})

// example usage
console.log(...range(1, 1000))
```

Answer (score -1):

Generators now allow you to generate the number sequence lazily and using less memory for large ranges.

While the question specifically states ES2015, I expect a lot of Typescript users will end up here and the conversion to ES is straightforward...

```
function range(end: number): IterableIterator<number>;
// tslint:disable-next-line:unified-signatures
function range(begin: number, end: number): IterableIterator<number>;

function *range(begin: number, end: number = NaN): IterableIterator<number> {
    let num = 0;
    if (isNaN(end)) {
        end = begin;
    } else {
        num = begin;
    }
    while (num < end) {
        yield num++;
    }
}
```

The first two function declarations are just to provide more informative completion suggestions in your IDE.

Comment: Aaaaand you can tell I didn't read all the existing answers before posting :-/