# Convert array to array of objects with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
optimizedRoute = ['Bengaluru', 'Salem', 'Erode', 'Tiruppur', 'Coimbatore']

result = [
  {start: bengaluru, end: salem},
  {start: salem, end: erode},
  {start: erode, end: tiruppur},
  {start: tiruppur, end: coimbatore},
]
```

I want to convert `optimizedRoute` to result. I want to do this with ES6 `.reduce()`. Here is what I've tried:

```
const r = optimizedRoute.reduce((places, place, i) => {
  const result: any = [];
  places = []
  places.push({
    startPlace: place,
    endPlace: place
  });
  // result.push ({ startplace, endplace, seats: 4 });
  // console.log(result);
  return places;
}, {});
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `reduce` for getting start and end part of the route and return the end for the next start.

```
getParts = a => (                   // take a as array and return an IIFE
    r => (                          // with an initialized result array
        a.reduce((start, end) => (  // reduce array by taking two values
            r.push({ start, end }), // push short hand properties
            end                     // and take the last value as start value for next loop
        )),
        r                           // finally return result
    )
)([]);                              // call IIFE with empty array
```

```js
const getParts = a => (r => (a.reduce((start, end) => (r.push({ start, end }), end)), r))([]);

var optimizedRoute = ['Bengaluru', 'Salem', 'Erode', 'Tiruppur', 'Coimbatore']

console.log(getParts(optimizedRoute));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

**@EDIT** Grégory NEUT *adding explaination*

```js
// Two thing to know first :

// When no initial value is provided,
// Array.reduce takes the index 0 as first value and start to loop at index 1

// Doing (x, y, z)
// Will execute the code x, y and z

// Equivalent to :

// x;
// y;
// z;

let ex = 0;

console.log((ex = 2, ex = 5, ex = 3));

// So about the code

const getParts = (a) => {
  // We are creating a new function here so we can have an array where to
  // push data to
  const func = (r) => {
    // Because there is no initial value
    //
    // Start will be the value at index 0 of the array
    // The loop is gonna start at index 1 of the array
    a.reduce((start, end) => {
      console.log(start, end);

      r.push({
        start,
        end,
      });

      return end;
    });

    return r;
  };

  return func([]);
};

// Equivalent
const getPartsEquivalent = (a) => {
  const r = [];

  // Because there is no initial value
  //
  // Start will be the value at index 0 of the array
  // The loop is gonna start at index 1 of the array
  a.reduce((start, end) => {
    console.log(start, end);

    r.push({
      start,
      end,
    });

    return end;
  });

  return r;
};

var optimizedRoute = ['Bengaluru', 'Salem', 'Erode', 'Tiruppur', 'Coimbatore']

console.log(getPartsEquivalent(optimizedRoute));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's impressive but tough to get it!

Comment: Even though this might be a (good) solution, I think this is too difficult for the OP to understand given skills of OP.

Comment: Nina, could you add some more detail to explain the steps of this awesome one-liner?

Comment: @Nina Scholz I can't understand why the first pushed value is not `{ start: undefined, end: 'Bengaluru',} `. Is this something about reduce ignoring the first value when there is no initial value ?

Comment: I've got my response [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Description) the first value is the index 0 value when no intiial value is provided (and loop start at 1).

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT, right, if reduce does not start with an initial value, then the first two elements are taken as accumulator and item. the index starts with `1`. for illustration, you might try this: `[4, 5, 6, 7].reduce((a, b, i) => (console.log(i, a, b), b));`

Comment: @NinaScholz Thx. I've took the liberty to add explaination about your code. Because it can be tricky to understand. ofc it's your post and your answer, I totally understand if you want to modify or delete what I've added.

Comment: @nina scholz, Thanks for your solutions. Why do you use closure in your solution?

Comment: you need a variable for the result and if you do not want to declare in the body, you could take a closure/IIFE for the variable. but the real answer is, i like the style ;-)

Comment: @NinaScholz I didn't know about the syntax (a, b, c) where all expressions are evaluated but the last is returned! That's pretty cool in that kind of situation, thank you very much!

Comment: @sjahan, it's the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), but actualy i am wondering where is it in my code?

Comment: @NinaScholz in the reducer function, you use it to return `end`: `(r.push({ start, end }), end)`. That's what puzzled me in the beginning! Really glad to have discovered this thanks to you :)

Comment: right, that pattern is two times in the code, one for returning `end` and the other for returning the result `r`.

Answer (score 12):

Another approach is to use `map`  method in combination with `slice`. For `map` function, you have to pass a `callback` function as *argument* which will be applied for every item from your given *array*.

```js
optimizedRoute = ['Bengaluru', 'Salem', 'Erode', 'Tiruppur', 'Coimbatore']
var result = optimizedRoute
                .slice(0, -1)
                .map((item, index) => ({start : item, end : optimizedRoute[index + 1]}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't really understand the "with reduce" requirement, since the corresponding code using a loop is immediately readable and requires no explanation:

```js
const optimizedRoute = ['Bengaluru', 'Salem', 'Erode', 'Tiruppur', 'Coimbatore'];
const result = new Array(optimizedRoute.length - 1);

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
  result[i] = {
    start: optimizedRoute[i],
    end: optimizedRoute[i + 1]
  };
}

console.log(result)
```

It's fun to do clever things sometimes but some of the answers are very complicated compared to this!

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example with `reduce`. I'm not sure this is the most natural way to do this though!

Using `reduce` feels quite overkill and in that kind of case (but that's just my opinion), where I'd naturally use an index, well, I'd go for a simple `for` loop.

```js
const optimizedRoute = ['Bengaluru', 'Salem', 'Erode', 'Tiruppur', 'Coimbatore'];
let startCity;
const result = optimizedRoute.reduce((acc, city) => {
  if(startCity) {
    acc.push({start: startCity, end: city});
  }
  startCity = city;
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for `reduce`, here is one way to do it:

```js
let optimizedRoute = ['Bengaluru', 'Salem', 'Erode', 'Tiruppur', 'Coimbatore']
   
let res = optimizedRoute.reduce((accum, item, i)=>{
   if(i == optimizedRoute.length - 1) 
      return accum;
   accum.push({start: item, end: optimizedRoute[i+1]})
   return accum;
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

`reduce` doesn't really fit the bill here as you're not trying to reduce the array to a single value.

In a perfect world we would have [multi-array `map` version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)#Language_comparison), usually known as `zip`, that we could use like

```
const result = zipWith(optimisedRoute.slice(0, -1),
                       optimisedRoute.slice(1),
                       (start, end) => ({start, end}));
```

but there is none in JavaScript. The best alternative is to `map` over a range of indices into the route using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
const result = Array.from({length: optimisedRoute.length - 1}, (_, index) => {
     const start = optimisedRoute[index];
     const end = optimisedRoute[index + 1];
     return {start, end};
});
```

Comment: This approach is very similar to what Mihai Alexandru-Ionut and Tom Fenech did, you should upvote their answers too!

Comment: @saila Oops, fixed. The flow is pretty simple, `Array.from({length: …}, …)`  is a [known trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36947847/1048572) that is basically equivalent to `range(0, …).map(…)`

Comment: @ Bergi which is best as per o notations.

Comment: @saila I think all the solutions presented here have linear runtime

Answer (score 2):

The following code is using of `Spread operator`, `Ternary operator` and `Array.reduce`.

```js
const optimizedRoute = [
  'Bengaluru',
  'Salem',
  'Erode',
  'Tiruppur',
  'Coimbatore',
];

// Look if we are at dealing with the last value or not
// If we do only return the constructed array
// If we don't, add a new value into the constructed array.

// tmp is the array we are constructing
// x the actual loop item
// xi the index of the item
const lastItemIndex = optimizedRoute.length - 1;

const ret = optimizedRoute.reduce((tmp, x, xi) => xi !== lastItemIndex ? [
  ...tmp,

  {
    start: x,
 
    // We access to the next item using the position of
    // the current item (xi)
    end: optimizedRoute[xi + 1],
  },
] : tmp, []);

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 2):

I simplified nina scholz answer,
As per nina’s idea, use reduce for getting start and end part of the route and return the end for the next start.

```
getParts = a => {
  const result = [];
    a.reduce((start, end) => {
      result.push({ start, end });
      return end;
    });
    return result;
};
var optimizedRoute = ['Bengaluru', 'Salem', 'Erode', 'Tiruppur', 'Coimbatore'];
console.log(this.getParts(optimizedRoute));
```

Answer (score 0):

**I prefer readability** over just *short code that solves it*

```
optimizedRoute.reduce((routes, city, index) => {
  const firstCity = index === 0;
  const lastCity = index === optimizedRoute.length - 1;
  if (!firstCity) {
    routes.last().end = city;
  }
  if (!lastCity) {
    routes.push({ start: city });
  }
  return routes;
}, []);
```

Also, that solution made shorter but killing readability (at least for me), could be:

```
optimizedRoute.reduce((routes, city) => {
  routes.last().start = city;
  routes.push({ end: city });
  return routes;
}, [{}]).slice(1, -1);
```

And about `last()`, it's a function i normally use for readability:

```
Array.prototype.last = function() { 
  return this[this.length - 1] 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution with ReduceRight, if anyone is looking for.

```
optimizedRoute.reduceRight((acc, d, i, arr) => 
             i == 0 
                ? acc 
                : [{ start: arr[i -1], end: d }, ...acc]  
            , [])
```

Comment: Pls explain why downvote here, I added this answer if anyone is looking for solution with reduceRight (which is similar to reduce). Thanks.