# ES6 Replace custom array gen function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I keep writing array generation function so that I can invoke the map function on blank arrays of fixed sizes. Is there an expression I can chain a map invocation to so that I don't have to reference an array generation function from local vars?

The following code with function and for loop and all of its verbosity is what I'm trying to eradicate:

```
var genArray = resolution => {

  var arr = [];

  for (var i =0; i < resolution; i++){
    arr.push(i);
  }

  return arr;
};
```

I'm looking for a similar interface as below but without the above code.

```
var result = genArray(10).map( i  => {
  return i + 1;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Maybe: `var result = [...Array(10)].map((_,i)=>i+1);`

Comment: see also [functional way to iterate over range (ES6/7)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30650961/1048572)

Comment: A more elaborate explanation of [...Array(resolution).keys()] would have sufficed but I suppose I got what I needed here.

Comment: @Emanegux, yeah, but in your example, you should add `.slice(1)` at the end to remove the `0`

Comment: whey the underscore in map((_,i)=>i+1) though?