# Template literals to initialize an array of given length

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I bumped into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529814/is-there-a-functional-way-to-init-an-array-in-javascript-es6) (how to init an array like `[{id: 1},{id: 2},...]`).

Accepted answer is:

```js
let sampleData = Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i) => ({id:i}))

console.log(sampleData)
```

And there are plenty others.
However, I thought of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as a solution, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

What I have so far is:

```js
var i = 0;
var arr = `[${"{id:++i},".repeat(10)}]`
console.log("As a string",arr);
console.log("Evaluated",eval(arr));
```

However, it uses `eval` which I know it's wrong.

I also tried

```js
var i = 0;
var arr = `[${"{id:${++i}},".repeat(10)}]`
console.log(arr);
```

But I have yet to somehow call the back ticks on this string (something like `TemplateLiteralFunction.call` on `arr`), to parse those expressions.
And instead of writting a tag function I'd just write a function called `initArray(ofLength)`.

So, is there anyway you can use template literals without `eval` or tag functions and achieve an array of a given length filled with values? Perhaps somehow nesting template literals?

Comment: Using a template litteral means you are working with a string in the end, and it won't be very good in a performance point of view. You can try to use `JSON.parse`, which is better than `eval` but no more `++i`... :/

Comment: well yes in the end `JSON.parse` will be needed, but I've yet to create the JSON compliant string with the `++i` already evaluated. Performance is not a problem here. It can be slow, what I'm wondering is if it is possible without `eval` or tag functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. Calling the
>   constructor directly can create functions dynamically, but suffers
>   from security and similar (but far less significant) performance
>   issues similar to eval. However, unlike eval, the Function constructor
>   allows executing code in the global scope, prompting better
>   programming habits and allowing for more efficient code minification.

```js
var template = `[${"{\"id\":${++i}},".repeat(10)}]`
template = template.replace(/,]$/,']'); //replace last comma

var parser = new Function("{i}", "return `" + template + "`;");
var arr = parser({i:0});
console.log(JSON.parse(arr));
```

Comment: Yup. +1 although it's very close to `eval` but I failed to specify Function constructor so that's my bad. I will wait some time to see if there's a cleaner solution otherwise I'll accept yours. Thanks! Hai Romania!