# Create an array from 1 number, (which increments)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I create an array, which increments up to a certain number?

For example, I have a variable, with the value of 3:

```
const totalNumber = 3;
```

Is it possible, to convert this to an array, but the array increments from every number, up to and including 3?

For example, I would want the out put to be:

```
[1,2,3]
```

So if the value was **10**, output would be:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529814/is-there-a-functional-way-to-init-an-array-in-javascript-es6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use loop

```js
const totalNumber = 3;
var arr = [];

for(var i=1; i<=totalNumber; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a simple `for..loop` to hanlde this

```
function arrayFromArg(totalNumber) {
    let newArray = [];
    for ( let i = 1 ; i <= totalNumber ; i++ ) {
        newArray.push(i)
    }
    return newArray;
}

console.log(arrayFromArg(3))
console.log(arrayFromArg(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and pass the number as the length of the array:

```js
const getArr = length => Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i + 1);

console.log(getArr(3));
console.log(getArr(10));
```

This is actually a private case of the [range function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Sequence_generator_range):

```js
const range = (start, stop, step = 1) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));

console.log(range(1, 3));
console.log(range(1, 10));
```