# Can faker be used to create fake JSON data

Tags: node.js, json, npm, faker

I was wondering if there is a way to set up a fake data (information) such as a `name` and `email` and have it stored in a JSON file.

I known faker can be used with node and NPM to create fake data in JS but what about with JSON?

Comment: If you want a quick browser based tool to generate some json data, try http://www.json-generator.com/

Comment: sadly I want to be able to do this using node and npm

Comment: So all you want to do is to save the faker results to a json file?

Answer (score 1):

One more [example](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server-36da8680136d) generates ten users and writes them to a `data.json` file.

**employees.js**

```
let faker = require('faker');
let fs = require('fs');

function generateEmployees() {
  let employees = [];
  for (let id = 1; id <= 10; id++) {
    let firstName = faker.name.firstName();
    let lastName = faker.name.lastName();
    let email = faker.internet.email();
    employees.push({
      id: id,
      first_name: firstName,
      last_name: lastName,
      email: email,
    });
  }
  return { employees: employees };
}
module.exports = generateEmployees;

let dataObj = generateEmployees();
fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(dataObj, null, '\t'));
```

---

### Serving fake data with JSON Server

```
$ json-server employees.js
```

[image]

Now you can click on the **Resources** link to see the result.

---

### Update

Inspired by [@le_m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42863131/6904888), you can generate dummy data without using a for loop:

```
let faker = require('faker');
let fs = require('fs');

const generateEmployee = () => {
  return {
    id: faker.random.uuid(),
    first_name: faker.name.firstName(),
    last_name: faker.name.lastName(),
    email: faker.internet.email(),
  };
};

const generateEmployees = (numUsers) => {
  return Array.from({ length: numUsers }, generateEmployee);
};

let dataObj = generateEmployees(10);
fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(dataObj, null, '\t'));
```

Then, simply start your server using the following command:

```
$ node employees.js
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var faker = require('faker');
var fs = require('fs');

var data = {};

data.name = faker.name.findName();
data.email = faker.internet.email();

fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

Comment: this saves the file as a json file but not in json format :-(

Comment: is there a way to set it so that I would be able to say add 10 new user records to the json file

Comment: Sure, there is a way. Start with an empty results array and generate the faker data inside a loop. Push to the results array each time. Then when the loop is finished, write the stringified results to your file.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped

Comment: Good luck. Also, check out this question for pushing to an array from a loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491101/javascript-create-array-from-for-loop